# Loop through numbered properties to generate inputs in Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-pages

I have a model with 34 numbered properties in it as shown below

```
Public Class ViewModel
{
    public string RatingCategory01 { get; set; }
    public string RatingCategory02 { get; set; }
    public string RatingCategory03 { get; set; }
    //...and so on until category #34
}
```

Rather than code an input for each category in Razor Pages, I would like to use a loop to iterate through all the categories and generate the appropriate control groups.  I have tried the code below:

```
<tbody>
    @for (var i = 1; i < 35; i++)
    {
        string n;

        @if (i > 0 && i < 10)
        {
            n = "RatingCategory0" + i.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            n = "RatingCateogry" + i.ToString();
        }
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label asp-for="@string.Format("RatingCategory" + n)" class="control-label"></label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select asp-for="@string.Format("RatingCategory" + n)" asp-items="Model.CategoryRatingSelectList">
                    <option value="">Select</option>
                    </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input asp-for="@string.Format("RemedialTime" + n)" class="form-control" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

When I build the project and navigate to the page, I get this error:

> InvalidOperationException: Templates can be used only with field
>   access, property access, single-dimension array index, or
>   single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

I'm not sure if I am on the right track here.  I would really like to create a loop to generate these inputs so make future maintenance and changes easier. It's probably pretty obvious from my code/question that I am pretty new to this, so any help is appreciated.

EDIT TO ADD SOLUTION:

I used the solution provided by Ed Plunkett which I have checked below.  I altered it a bit and ended up creating a new class called 'Rating' because I found that in practice I needed a more complex object.  Inside my view is now

```
public List<Rating> Ratings = { get; set; }
```

In the controller, I use a loop to add as many empty ratings as I need to the list depending on the number I need.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 34; i++)
    {
        vm.Ratings.Add(new Rating());
    }
```

Though this will likely be updated to use something other than a hard-coded number as the application evolves.

Finally, I used a loop in the view to create a group of controls for every Rating in my List.  In this case it is a TableRow containing different controls in different columns:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Ratings.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Ratings[i].Category)
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select asp-for="Ratings[i].RatingValue" asp-items="Model.CategoryRatingSelectList">
                        <option value="">Select</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input asp-for="Ratings[i].RemediationMinutes" class="form-control" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

I've found that the data in this group of inputs can be bound as a List by simply including

```
List<Rating> Ratings
```

in the parameters on whichever method runs when the form is submitted.

Comment: `public List<String> RatingCategory { get; set; } = new List<String>();`. If you have 34 of something and the names differ only by an index number, that's a collection, not 34 distinct properties with sequentially numbered names. Then you can enumerate the 34 items with a `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want instead of those 34 properties and their implied 34 `RemedialTime` siblings:

```
public List<String> RatingCategory { get; set; } = new List<String>();
public List<String> RemedialTime { get; set; } = new List<String>();
```

If you have 34 of something and the names differ only by an index number, that's a collection, not 34 distinct properties with sequentially numbered names. Then you can enumerate the 34 items with a `foreach` loop, or index them individually as `RatingCategory[0]` through `RatingCategory[33]`. In C#, collection indexes start at zero, so the first one is `0` and the thirty-fourth one is `33`. You get used to it.

You should also look up what String.Format() does. `String.Format("Foo" + 1)` is exactly the same as `"Foo" + 1`.

Comment: I see what you're saying.  Would I iterate through/index them in the view to generate the inputs or in the controller when the form is submitted?

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your model class to dictionary;

```
var viewModel = new ViewModel()
{
    RatingCategory01 = "a",
    RatingCategory02 = "b",
    RatingCategory03 = "c"
};
var dictionaryModel = viewModel.GetType()
    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
    .ToDictionary(prop => prop.Name, prop => prop.GetValue(viewModel, null));
```

Then you can iterate the dictionary in the view.